# is wrapper necessary in async await structure

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# and I've been learning asynchronous programming. So I've been trying to make a simple UI with a label and a button and when I press the button, the label text changes and I've been taught to do it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CallChangeLable();
            label1.Text = "Loading ...";
        }

        private async void CallChangeLable()
        {
            var result = await ChangeLabelAsync("Oliver");
            label1.Text = result;
        }

        private Task<string> ChangeLabelAsync(string name)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => ChangeLable(name));
        }

        private string ChangeLable(string name)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return $"Hi {name}";
        }
```

now I've tried this code without the wrapper step:

```
private Task<string> ChangeLabelAsync(string name)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => ChangeLable(name));
        }
```

Of course I moved the task.run method to somewhere else and I modified the naming and the code still works fine, the UI is still responsive. My question is, why is the wrapper step important and can I skip it?

Here's the modified code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CallChangeLable();
            label1.Text = "Loading ...";
        }

        private async void CallChangeLable()
        {
            var result = await Task.Run(() => ChangeLable("Mahmoud"));
            label1.Text = result;
        }

        private string ChangeLable(string name)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return $"Hi {name}";
        }
```

Comment: "I moved the task.run method to somewhere else and I modified the naming " can you also post the modified code?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31907427/1997232). Making `...Async()` wrapper method to call synchronous method is bad idea indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, why is the wrapper step important and can I skip it?

Actually, you *shouldn't* have a wrapper. [Providing a fake-asynchronous method is an antipattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to ensure that you don't block the UI thread - So don't skip it.

Stephen Cleary has some excellent articles on the subject:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

For Async/Await programming in general take a look at the best practices from an old msdn post also by Stephen Cleary:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

using SynchronizationContext you can do something like this

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SynchronizationContext.Current.Post((txt)=>{
        label1.Text = txt;
```

},"Loading....");
        }