# C# async/sync versions of Web Call return different types

Tags: c#, async-await

I am still an async/await novice, but I think I am getting a better grip on it. I am writing for suggestions on how to handle a certain scenario. The scenario is that, a certain web service has a method with both sync and async versions, but the versions have different return types.

`getDocs()` returns `document[]`, which is what I want.

`getDocsAsync()` returns `Task<getDocsResponse>`, where `getDocsResponse` has a (non-awaitable) property of type `document[]`.

To further complicate matters, I am calling this method inside a delegate I am passing to another method. (I am doing this so I can, at will, either get fresh data from the server, or use saved data that I have cached from earlier calls. The delegate that uses the saved data is basically `Task.FromResult(myDocArray)`. Whether fresh or cached, I have more code that is going to process the `document` objects.)

The main question is, if I call the async version, can I await the return value's property? If so, how? If not, do I have to wait for the result to get the property (as in, `response.Result`)?

(Simplified) code sample: Call the sync method, but wrap in a task. This seems like it would work fine, and is what I would do if there wasn't an async version of the `getDocs` method.

```
Func<Task<document[]>> f = async () => {
    var docs = Task.Run(() => service.GetDocs());
    return await docs;
}
```

(Simplified) code sample: Call the async version, but then ... ?

```
Func<Task<document[]>> f = async () => {
    var docs = service.GetDocsAsync();

    // this seems silly to call .Result, only to wrap it in an awaitable task.
    return await Task.FromResult(docs.Result.documents);
}
```

Both versions appear to work fine, but in this case, the async route seems awkward. Is there a better way to handle such a case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `.Result` on task you did not `await`  as it in most cases lead to deadlock ([await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock), [await works but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks))

I think you want to just return `documents` from your async delegate:

```
Func<Task<document[]>> f = async () => {
    Task<getDocsResponse> task = service.GetDocsAsync();
    getDocsResponse response = await task;
    return response.documents;
}
```

Note that result of the async method is always `Task<>` of whatever type you `return`. You don't need to wrap result in `Task.FromResult`.

`FromResult` is useful when you need to match `Task<T>` signature but have only  synchronous method. So synchronous call you have may be rewritten synchronously (unless you really need async code, but generally it is not recommended practice - [What is the best way for wrapping synchronous code into asynchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907427/what-is-the-best-way-for-wrapping-synchronous-code-into-asynchronous-method))

```
Func<Task<document[]>> f = () => Task.FromResult(service.GetDocs());
```

Comment: Oh yeah that works great AND makes sense! Thanks so much!